# Disable double quotes

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

When I use the below code, it is adding double quotes at the starting and end of the data. Ideally, this is valid as I am telling it is a pipe delimeted file and pipe is coming in the data. But I have a requirement not to get double quote added in the starting and end of the data. Is there a way to acheive this?

```
data = [{"Cnt": 'A|1'},{"Cnt": 'B|2'}]
rdd = sc.parallelize(data)
df_test = rdd.toDF()   
df_test.repartition(1).write.option('header','false').option("delimiter",'|').option("quoteAll", 'false').option("quote", None).mode("overwrite").csv(path_of_file)
```

Data in the file looks like below after exporting

```
"A|1"
"B|2"
```

But I need the data in the file like below.

```
A|1
B|2
```

Apache Spark version - 3.3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduced the same code what you have done,
even i got the data in quotes as shown[image] below

Later, I tried saving in text format then i got output without quotes.

```
data = [{"Cnt": 'A|1'},{"Cnt": 'B|2'}]
rdd = sc.parallelize(data)
df_test = rdd.toDF()
df_test.repartition(1).write.option('header','false').option("delimiter",'|').option("quoteAll", 'false').option("quote", None).mode("overwrite").text("/demot/")
```

[image]

Comment: That's great Jay. Its working. By the way, I would like to know if there is any drawback on writing using `text` method compared to `csv` method

Comment: Both formats have their advantages and disadvantages, choosing between them is depends on your specific requirements. The main difference is test format does not have defined schema and does not handle data types and null values. When you are using structured data then csv format preferred which can preserve schema and handle  data type and null values.

Comment: Thanks Jayshankar